# OpenCart local to live server

Tags: opencart

I have a localhost opencart install, where i do all my changes and push content and database to a live server (well i thought it works this way). I just did minor twig updates and removed all install products and replaced with mine, but on the live server the new products do not display. i dropped the database and imported the new local db but still nothing.

Am i missing a step or is there another way of doing this, i see some paid modules, which my client will not purchase.

followed the following steps to upload localsite to the server.

1. Copy all the OpenCart files from your existing web server to the new web server.
2. Export the OpenCart database and import it into the new server.
3. Edit config.php and admin/config.php. These files contain the filesystem paths to OpenCart folders, URLs to OpenCart frontend and admin, and database access details

live site still shows default/install opencart products.

Very new to opencart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right way it should show the products you have in your new db. One possible chance is you are using any caching plugin in Opencart that needs cache removal or the live server has some caching feature.

Comment: Hi @saqib, i don't have any caching plugin, its a clean install no plugins as yet. I also deleted cache files in the cache folder. not sure what could be the issue

Comment: Ok managed to get it to work finally, in the admin > system > maintenance > backup / restore i exported my local and imported on the live server cleared browser history and deleted cache files excluding the index.html file and it worked